# Having trouble with nginx configuration, The url example.com/blog/ is working but anything after that is throwing 404

Tags: nginx, url, nginx-location

I have  static html files at /var/www/public they are pointed at /
Location /  nd it is working perfectly.

but on location /blog i was planning to run bludit blog

The url /blog/ gives me the index.php but on anyother url like
/blog/create-your-own-content i am getting 404

Please help.

Here is the complete configuration

```
##
# This is the main Nginx configuration file.
# It should typically be located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# This file includes configuration snippets from other files.
# Those files are located in /etc/nginx/conf.d/.
##

# Default server configuration
server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # Listen for IPv6 connections on port 443
    listen 443 ssl; # Listen for IPv4 connections on port 443
    server_name insurancepadosi.in www.insurancepadosi.in; # Your domain names

    # SSL certificate configuration
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/insurancepadosi.in/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/insurancepadosi.in/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # SSL configuration options
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # Diffie-Hellman parameter for SSL

    # Root directory for the main website
    root /var/www/html/public;

    # Default index files
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # Main location block for handling requests to the root
    location / {
        # Try serving the requested file or directory,
        # fallback to displaying a 404 error if not found
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
    }

    # Location block for serving the blog at /blog

   location /blog/ {
                alias /var/www/html/bludit;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
               }
}


    location ~ ^/bl-content/(databases|workspaces|pages|tmp)/.*$ { }


    location ^~ /blog/bl-content/databases/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ^~ /blog/bl-content/workspaces/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ^~ /blog/bl-content/pages/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ^~ /blog/bl-kernel/*.php {
        deny all;
    }
    # Additional security configuration to deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# Server block for handling HTTP traffic and redirecting to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80 default_server; # Listen for HTTP connections on port 80
    listen [::]:80 default_server; # Listen for HTTP IPv6 connections on port 80
    server_name insurancepadosi.in www.insurancepadosi.in; # Your domain names

    # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Both the `location` and `alias` statements should end with a `/`. Also, the `try_files` statement should end with `/blog/index.php?$args;`

Comment: Hey @RichardSmith , 

Thank you for quick response.

I have updated the config to 

location /blog/ {
                alias /var/www/html/bludit/;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ blog/index.php?$args; 

I am still getting 404 on any url after /blog/<xxxx>

Comment: That configuration cannot generate 404 on `/blog/<xxxx>` unless the application `index.php` is generating it. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that it matches the configuration in your question. Check the access log for the exact URL causing the 404 response. Use `curl -I` to view the response headers for evidence that the response is originating from PHP and not Nginx.

Comment: Also, check the error log.

Comment: 1) Error log has noting 

2) but access log states 
 GET /blog/create-your-own-content HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "https://xxxxx.in/blog/" 

3) as per nginx -T there is only config file and it as per the changes i did. 

4) The 404 i think is nginx because it is  nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) on the page

Comment: I have a feeling this confiuration is looking for file create-your-own-content  when we enter /blog/create-your-own-content rather than pointing it to index.php. 
Could that be the case?

Comment: Here is the official suggested confiuration 

https://docs.bludit.com/en/webservers/nginx

Comment: Hey it started working.

Comment: By adding this line 

if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /blog/index.php last; }